# Is there any way to cause a redirect using Apollo Server?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm moving all my non-graphql endpoints to GraphQL using Apollo.

One of these endpoints requires a server side redirect instead of returning data to the client.

Currently, I use express and do `res.redirect` but I cannot see a way to get access to the `res` object with Apollo. Is it possible to get it in the resolver context maybe?

Is there any chance I can do that using Apollo Server?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple solution

**First Step:** Add Context while creating the apollo server object
[image: Add Context while creating server object]

**Second Step** Then access res object in your resolver **context.res.redirect**
[image: Resolver Function]